# Is there literature on a de Rham analogue of the Mumford-Tate group or ell-adic monodromy group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. The theory of motives predicts that for each cohomology theory, there should be a distinguished Zariski closed subgroup of $GL(H^k_{\bullet}(X))$, the motivic Galois group. This group has conjectural descriptions for Betti and $\ell$-adic cohomology, and I am wondering if there is any literature on this group for de Rham cohomology.

The Betti cohomology $H^k_B(X)$ is a rational Hodge structure, hence there is a representation $\mathrm{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{G}_m\to GL(H^k_B(X)\otimes\mathbb{R})$. The Mumford-Tate group $MT^k(X)\leq GL(H^k_B(X))$ is defined to be the smallest Zariski-closed subgroup containing the image of the representation. The Hodge conjecture would imply that $MT^k(X)$ has finite index in the Betti motivic Galois group.

The $\ell$-adic cohomology $H^k(X;\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ is a representation of the absolute Galois group, and the $\ell$-adic monodromy group $G_\ell^k(X)\leq GL(H^k(X;\mathbb{Q}_\ell))$ is defined to be the smallest Zariski-closed subgroup containing the image of the representation. The Tate conjecture would imply that $G_\ell^k(X)$ is the full $\ell$-adic motivic Galois group.

> Is there any literature on an analogue of the Mumford-Tate group or the $\ell$-adic monodromy group inside $GL(H^k_{dR}(X))$?

I believe that a conjecture of Ogus would imply that the de Rham motivic Galois group is smallest Zariski closed subgroup whose $\mathbb{Q}_p$ points contain $F_p$ for all sufficiently large $p$ (where $F_p\in GL(H^k_{dR}(X))(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is the crystalline Frobenius). However I have some doubt about this, because André's book on motives states the relationship between the Hodge conjecture and the Mumford-Tate group (Proposition 7.2.2.1), and the relationship between the Tate conjecture and the $\ell$-adic monodromy group (Proposition 7.3.2.1), but does not give an analogous statement for the Ogus conjecture.

I also believe that the period conjecture of Grothendieck would imply that the de Rham motivic Galois group is the smallest Zariski closed subgroup containing all elements $\varphi\in GL(H^k_{dR}(X))(\mathbb{Q})$ whose image in $GL(H^k_{B}(X))(\mathbb{C})$ under the Betti-de Rham comparison isomorphism is contained in $GL(H^k_{B}(X))(\mathbb{Q})$. However, I also cannot find a statement like this in André's book.

Comment: Your statement for the period conjecture is not the right one - it implies that the motivic Galois group of a disjoint union of $n$ points is $GL_n$. The right statement would be to take the smallest Zariski closed subset defined over $\mathbb Q$ containing the period matrix, translating it by any rational point of itself so it contains the identity, and then taking the subgroup it generates - this should be the motivic fundamental group of the Tannakian category of mixed Hodge structures.

Comment: In general, it's wrong to think of these groups as being associated to cohomology theories, but rather to the (Tannakian) categories these cohomology theories end up in - Galois representations, mixed Hodge structures, etc. So which structure you consider to be the de Rham Galois group depends on which category you want de Rham cohomology to lie in.

Comment: If the only thing you want is that it conjecturally agree with the motivic Galois group, you have many options - for instance you could take the Mumford-Tate or $\ell$-adic group, transfer it to de Rham cohomology by a period map, and take a $\mathbb Q$-Zariski closure.

Comment: Hello @Julian Rosen, Can you help me for the problem appearing here :
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389391/looking-for-the-exact-and-the-precise-statement-of-ogus-conjecture ; Thank you.  :)

Comment: @YoYo My understanding of the Ogus conjecture is basically just Conjecture 7.1.7.3 from André's book.