# Cycles in algebraic de Rham cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-cycles, chern-classes, derham-cohomology

Let $F$ be a number field, $S$ a finite set of places, and $X$ a smooth projective $\mathscr{O}_{F,S}$-scheme with geometrically connected fibers. For each point $t\in \text{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{F,S})$, there is a Chern class map $$c_{1,t}:\text{Pic}(X_t)\to H^2_{dR}(X_t),$$
where $H^2_{dR}$ denotes algebraic de Rham cohomology. (See below for one construction of $c_1$.)

> Let $c\in H^2_{dR}(X_F)$ be an element so that there exists a non-zero integer $N$ such that $Nc$ specializes to an element of the image $c_{1,t}\otimes k(t)$, for almost all closed points $t\in \text{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{F,S})$. Is $c$ in the image of $$c_{1, F}: \text{Pic}(X_F)\otimes F\to H^2_{dR}(X_F)?$$
> Here $c_{1,F}$ means $c_{1, \eta}$, for $\eta$ the generic point of $\text{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{F,S})$, and $k(t)$ is the residue field of $t$.

**Is the answer to the above question (and its evident analogue for higher degree Chern classes/cycle class maps) known in general? Does the question have a name, and is it discussed somewhere?**

In general, given a cohomology theory, there's some conjectural description of the image of the cycle class map (the Hodge conjecture for Betti/de Rham cohomology, the Tate conjecture for $\ell$-adic cohomology) -- my motivation for asking the question is that I realized I hadn't seen such a conjecture for algebraic de Rham cohomology.

---

I'll now give a brief description of $c_1$, for completeness. Let $\Omega^\bullet_{dR}$ be the algebraic de Rham complex of some variety $Y$. There's a natural map $$d\log: \mathscr{O}_Y^*[-1]\to \Omega^{\bullet}_{dR}$$ sending a nowhere-vanishing function $f$ to $df/f$. Applying $H^2$ gives the desired map $$c_1:\text{Pic}(Y)=H^1(Y, \mathscr{O}_Y^*)=H^2(Y, \mathscr{O}_Y^*[-1])\overset{d\log}{\longrightarrow} H^2_{dR}(Y).$$

By construction, it factors through $F^1H_{dR}^2(Y)$, the first piece of the Hodge filtration.

---

Some remarks, added September 6, 2022:

- François Charles has explained to me how to give a positive answer to the above question for divisors on Abelian varieties, using Bost's work on foliations. I think a similar argument handles products of curves.
- One natural strategy is to try to find a prime where the Picard rank does not jump. This will not work, unfortunately; there are varieties where the Picard rank jumps at *every* prime, e.g. the square of a non-CM elliptic curve.
- The question can be reduced to the case of surfaces, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Clearly, this is a special case of the Litt conjecture. :)

Comment: An analogue of Hodge and Tate conjecture with respect to algebraic de Rham cohomology is the Grothendieck period conjecture: if $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$, then conjecturally the image of the cycle class map is given by the intersection
$ H^{2k}_{\mathrm{sing}}(X^{\mathrm{an}},\mathbf Q(k)) \cap H^{2k}_{\mathrm{dR}}(X/{\overline{\mathbf{Q}}})$.

Comment: @DanPetersen: Good point. To be honest my actual motivation was: Simpson's conjecture says that a local system underlies an integral VHS iff it arises from geometry; this is the non-abelian analogue of the Hodge conjecture. The Fontaine-Mazur conjecture says a local system is arithmetic iff it arises from geometry; this is the non-abelian analogue of the Tate conjecture. Now there is a conjecture that a flat vector bundle has almost all p-curvatures nilpotent iff it comes from geometry (the p-curvature conjecture is closely related) -- I was wondering what the "abelian" analogue of this is.

Comment: You don't lose generality by taking $N = 1$, right? Because $N$ is invertible in $F$ and in $\kappa(t)$ for almost all $t$, and all maps are maps of vector spaces.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: yes, I was hedging because otherwise specialization isn’t defined everywhere. But since it’s an almost-everywhere condition it’s fine to take N=1 if you don’t mind specialization not being defined somewhere.

Comment: Related in spirit, but I think a bit different, is the Ogus conjecture, discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389391/looking-for-the-exact-and-the-precise-statement-of-ogus-conjecture (see in particular the reference to Yves Andre's "Une Introduction aux Motifs"). Ogus' conjecture is the only one I'm aware of in the neighborhood of what you are proposing.

Comment: @PeterScholze: Thanks! This does indeed seem quite related, and indeed the discussion on page 81 of "Une Introduction aux Motifs" is closely related to the argument François Charles sketched for the case of Abelian varieties.